# on the minimization of: $E[((Y-f(X))^2|X]$

Tags: self-study, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am having troubles solving this exercise:

Deduce that the random variable $f(X)$ that minimizes $E[((Y-f(X))^2|X]$ is $$f(X)= E[X|Y]. $$

I proceeded in this way: $$E[(Y-f(X) + E[Y|X] - E[Y|X])^2|X]$$
$$E[(Y-E[X|Y])^2 + (E[Y|X] - f(X))^2 +2(E[Y|X] - f(X))(Y-E[X|Y])|X]$$

Now it seems to me that $f(X)= E[X|Y] $ is indeed right if the last terms were $\ge 0$ but

$$2(E[Y|X] - f(X))(Y-E[X|Y])$$ can be negative. right? so how would you solve this?